# How to derive an RC transfer function to plot in MATLAB?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I recently came across this circuit which modifies a signal going into an ADC.  My gut feeling is that it is some sort of low pass filter but I would really like to derive the transfer function so I can plot the response in MATLAB.

```
----------------------R2-------------- 
       |       |              |
Vin    C1      R1             C2     Vout
       |       |              |
--------------------------------------
```

My nodal and mesh analysis is a little bit rusty so help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll want to factor in the series input impedance from Vin or C1 will have no effect. It might also be useful to factor in the impedance of the ADC at Vout to get a full idea. You can always stitch it together in SPICE and use AC analysis to find the response then.

Comment: R1, C1 doesn't do anything there if the input is an ideal voltage source.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using matlab, there is no need to solve the circuit.

You can just build the circuit as is in Simulink and get that to solve it, you need values for the components though, there is no way to graph this if it is left symbolic.

your other choice is to solve it in laplace and give matlab the numerator and denominator and get it to plot the bode of the transfer function for example.

you got told in a comment that you need a series impedance to V1 for C1 and R1 to make sense and they are right, since they are parallel I can just say that V(R1) = V1 and solve that one loop to get the transfer function.

$$
\frac{V_2}{V_1}=\frac{1}{SC_2R_2+1}
$$

you can substitute S for w which is 2pif where f is frequency.

it is possible I made mistakes, so just comment and point them out I guess.

Comment: Only possible if you have simulink+simpowerSystens (or simscape)